# jQuery - Move element that has a blob background image

Tags: jquery, blob, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it possible to move an element with jquery that has a blob background image?

For example the style attribute is the following: style="background-image: url("blob:http://localhost/b7e08807-b94f-4448-95db-1702c4508172");

When I try using append or insertAfter it displays an error in the console saying the file doesn't exist.

It did exist originally because when a user adds an image on the website it shows a preview of the image and adds the blob image as the background.

I am looking for a way to either actually move the element instead of removing it and then inserting it or to re-create the blob file again from the blob url.

UPDATE:

The code I have at the moment to replace one div with the other is:

```
var old_id = $('.media-temp-selected-border').parent().attr('id');
var old_html = $('.media-temp-selected-border').parent().wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
$('.media-temp-selected-border').parent().unwrap();
                
var new_id = $(this).attr('id');
var new_html = $(this).wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
$(this).unwrap();
                
$(old_html).insertAfter('#'+new_id);
$(new_html).insertAfter('#'+old_id);
                
$('.media-temp-selected-border').parent().remove();
$(this).remove();
```

When I run this code it throws the error message that the blob file does not exist.

I have also tried this approach:

```
var original_background_image = $('.media-temp-selected-border').parent().css('background-image');
var original_data_name = $('.media-temp-selected-border').parent().attr('data-name');
var original_data_file = $('.media-temp-selected-border').parent().attr('data-file');
                
$.get(original_data_file).then(function(data) {
    var original_file = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/jpg' });
                
    var original_img = new Image();
    original_img.src = URL.createObjectURL(original_file);
                
    $(this).css('background-image', original_background_image);
    $(this).attr('data-name', original_data_name);
    $(this).attr('data-file', original_img.src);
});
                
var new_background_image = $(this).css('background-image');
var new_data_name = $(this).attr('data-name');
var new_data_file = $(this).attr('data-file');
                
$.get(new_data_file).then(function(data) {
    var new_file = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/jpg' });
                
    var new_img = new Image();
    new_img.src = URL.createObjectURL(new_file);
                
    $('.media-temp-selected-border').parent().css('background-image', new_background_image);
    $('.media-temp-selected-border').parent().attr('data-name', new_data_name);
    $('.media-temp-selected-border').parent().attr('data-file', new_img.src);
});
```

But again I get the error saying it doesn't exist.

The code I am using to create the blob image in the first place is:

```
var file = elem.files[i];

var img = new Image();
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

This code is called when the user initially adds an image and isn't anything to do with the examples above it.

The reason I am doing this is because on mobile devices I can't get jQuery Sortable to work.

I can get it working by using a library I found and then calling $('.added-photos').addTouch(); but the problem with this is it then won't allow swipe scrolling so the user is unable to scroll down the page.

I tried many different combinations of things to try to get this to work such as enabling/disabling sortable or adding a custom function to calculate the delay or using delay itself in sortable but unfortunately I've deleted the code I tried now.

UPDATE
I decided to stick with jquery sortable and add a button that the user clicks to turn the sortable on or off.

Comment: Can you post a snippet? --
You could try using .css('background-image', 'url("blob:http://localhost/b7e08807-b94f-4448-95db-1702c4508172")');

Comment: @DanielGonzabay Hi Daniel, thank you for your comment. I've updated the post with everything I've tried so far.